# Improper double integrals

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$$
\iint_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}{\ln\left(1 + 2x^{2} + y^{2}\right) \over 1+x^{2}+y^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
$$ 
using
$\ln\left(1 + 2x^{2} + y^{2}\right) \leq
\,\sqrt{\, 1 + x^{2} + y^{2}\,}\,$ and showed convergence by the comparison test, but according to my friends it diverges.

Who is right ?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\frac{1}{(1+x^{2}+y^{2})^{a}}$ converges if a>1 , 3/2 > 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral diverges as $x^2+y^2\to \infty$.  To see this, we note that

$$\begin{align}
\iint_{1\le x^2+y^2\le R}\frac{\log(1+2x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2+1}\,dx\,dy &\ge \frac{\log(2)}{2}\iint_{1\le x^2+y^2\le R}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy\\\\
&=\frac{\log(2)}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^R\frac{1}{r}\,dr\,d\theta\\\\
&=\pi \log(2R)\\\\
&\to \infty \,\,\text{as}\,\,R\to \infty
\end{align}$$

Comment: Elegent solution but can you explain the first inequality in more detail please? and also what is wrong with my attempt.

Comment: Thank you!  Much appreciative.  For $x^2+y^2\ge 1$, $\log(1+2x^2+y^2)\ge \log(1+x^2+y^2)\ge \log(2)$ and $\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}\ge \frac{1}{2(x^2+y^2)}$.